# Headers is resizing not columns with colResizable jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am using the [colResizable](https://github.com/alvaro-prieto/colResizable) jQuery plugin and this directive to resize table columns

```
.directive('colResizeable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                elem.colResizable({
                    liveDrag: true,
                    gripInnerHtml: "<div class='grip'></div>",
                    draggingClass: "dragging",
                    onDrag: function () {
                        //trigger a resize event, so width dependent stuff will be updated
                        $(window).trigger('resize');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
})
```

and I added a attribute **col-resizeable** on table selector

```html
<table id="myTable" style="display:block" name="form" class="table__body"
       on-scroll-end="vm.loadMoreListItems()" on-scroll-end-threshold="0"
       col-resizeable>
```

And added  `<script src="src/scripts/lib/less/colResizeable.js"></script>` also but when i am trying to resize the columns of the table only headers are moving not columns here is the image[image]

how can i make column resizable?

Comment: can you please confirm the element you are resizing?

Comment: What is the final html markup of headers and rest of the table?

Comment: It is always tricky when you mix jQuery DOM manipulation with AngularJS DOM manipulation. Are you using the `ng-repeat` directive to create the rows?

Comment: Yes i am using ng-repeat